# Find process running in CPU core Win10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cpu-usage, multi-core

I have a multi-core Win10 machine. Some process consumes 100% CPU in a core, while overall CPU consumption remains low.

I can identify the core - but not the process running in it. **Need to figure out which process is running in that core**. I cant find any built in tool in windows that shows process by core.

Any tool or PowerShell that could help?

Comment: This clearly does not answer you question but IMHO, let windows worry about the process affinity.  NOT IMPORTANT.  Resource usage on your system VERY IMPORTANT but worrying about what percent vs what core is irrelevant.  If you insist.. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902325/processes-running-on-a-particular-core)

Comment: I would not bother. I have the SysInternals stuff as well as Windows and none of this is shown. Overall CPU should run less than 5% more than 95% of the time on regular computers.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas - the link you gave was for linux not windows- that is what I need for windows.  My issue is- I need to identify and debug the process that is consuming a CPU core. I have a high powered machine with many cores and many processes running, I often/sometimes get unpredictable behavior - I see this 100% peg on a core- I reboot and am fine. Need a fix

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools show this, both `Process Explorer` and `Process Hacker` show the CPU per core and when hoovering over a core the process using most of the CPU.

With Windows tools, it is not so easy, `Resource Monitor`

```
perfmon.exe /res
```

shows the different cores, but not the process.

However if a process uses 100% of one core it should also use a good amount of total CPU on the machine, so just check any process with high CPU. You can always kill that process and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I have too many cores (96) - so if I check overall cpu usage for a process - it is all 1 and below - so that does not help.

Comment: OMG.. 96 cores??  OMG

Comment: Note that MS bought SysInternals, and the resource monitor can be reached directly from task manager in Win10 by clicking the "performance" tab and then clicking through to "resource monitor".